# I used to have a Trello sidebar in Chrome. Where can I find it?

Tags: trello, google-chrome-extensions

Here I am not talking about the *menu*-sidebar in Trello, but a "very small strip of Trello" that has split my screen in two parts: Chrome + Trello that sticks to the right side of my screen. It was very handy. I have switched computers and I lost it!